# PHP Myqsli Form automatically returning to previous page in Chrome but not in Edge?

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I have a form that submits fields to a database using mysqli that was working perfectly; however, I pulled up the form page in Chrome and tried to submit a new row to the db, only for the page to go back to the previous page when I tried to click on the form's text-areas. I tried clearing all of my browser history (cache, cookies, etc.) and asked a friend to try it on their Chrome browser, with the same result.

The kicker? It works in Edge. Makes no sense.

I've gone through the code and can't find any missing <'s or quotes, etc. Everything was working fine and I can't imagine why it would suddenly start doing this in Chrome.

(Note: I know this code is clunky and vulnerable to SQL injection, but I don't have any users/sensitive data to protect, for the moment. Also, I made no changes to head.php or any code (that I can recall), just confused as to why it would suddenly start redirecting me back to notebook.php as soon as I click on a text area in Chrome but not in Edge.)

1. Notebook_add.php

   ```
   $con = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'db');

   if (!$con) {
       echo "Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
       exit();
   }
   ?>
   <body>
   <div class="wrapper">
   <h1>Post Comments</h1>

   <?php
   include ('navbar.php');
   ?>

   <br>

   <form name="noteworthy" METHOD=POST action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>>
   <br>
   Title: <input type="text" name="title" id="$title" size="50"> <br>
   Link: <input type="text" name="link" id="$link" size="50"><br>
   Description: <TEXTAREA NAME="description" id="$description" ROWS="5" COLS="30"></TEXTAREA><br>
   <Input type="submit" name="enter" id="$enter" value="enter">
   </form>

   <?
   echo $submitted = date("Y-m-d");
   ?>

   <?
   $title = $_REQUEST['title'];
   $link = $_REQUEST['link'];
   $description = $_REQUEST['description'];
   $enter = $_REQUEST['enter'];


   if(isset($_REQUEST['enter'])){
   $submitted = date("Y-m-d");
   $sql = "INSERT INTO notes (title, link, description, submitted) VALUES ('$title','$link','$description','$submitted')";
   }

   if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
       echo "Records inserted successfully.";
       print "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=http:notebook.php' />";
   }

   // Close connection
   mysqli_close($con);
   ?>

   <div class="push"> </div>

   </div>

   <?php
   include 'footer.php';
   ?>

   </body>
   ```

Comment: use either js, or php header far more reliable. obligatory your code sin not safe from SQL injection attack

Comment: js: `window.location.href = 'your_url';`, php: `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');exit()` (remove any output before it)

Comment: AFAIK the form's method and action should be quoted. This way: method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"

Answer (score 0):

So what happened was that I had added a new menu item in my navbar.php and forgot to close the  link tag (e.g., " New menu item "). This made the entire php form into a link, so whenever I anywhere on it under my navbar I was returned to the previous page.

It is interesting that this didn't happen in Edge; perhaps there is some feature in Edge that automatically closes rogue  tags.

Anyway, thanks for responding. @Smith, thanks for the tip, I'm using the php head featured/location function instead of meta-refresh now.